# TraceFlag 15097

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, sql-server-2022

I wanna use traceflag 15097 and benefit from AVX-512 on SQL Server 2022. I saw some videos where they demonstrated the feature, however I didn’t find out how to use the extended events to monitor which cpu instruction (cpu_instructed_set_used) is used during execution of my t-sql code.
There are videos from MSFT where they demo it, however as often with MSFT no links so one can find out what code was used in the demo. Anybody having an idea how i get the information I’m looking for ?

Comment: What are you asking? Which XEvent contains `cpu_instruction_set_used`? If so `query_execution_column_store_segment_scan_started` in the debug channel. As returned by `select object_name from sys.dm_xe_object_columns where name = 'cpu_instruction_set_used'`

Comment: It also requires hardware (cpu ) support and AFAIK batch mode processing in the query execution. It's not guaranteed to be faster than not using it and you'll need to investigate the performance per cpu make/model.

Comment: Initially I had trouble to set up the proper extended event to monitor the behavior, however figures that out and now can see that my batch mode operations are indeed using AVX-512 instead of AVX-2. However the results are not really consistent. Went back to search all over but all I find is "improves performance" no video from MSFT or anybody else where I see the same query with AVX-2 vs AVX-512 and any significant performance improvement. I assume it will speed up the columnstore index scan, but a bit irritated that there is no straight forward demo showing it (at least I didn't find any)